# Is there a way to distinguish, whether a Qt widget got focus from mouse clicking or from table key pressing?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm  using  Qt5  on  windows. 
Is there a way to distinguish whether a Qt widget got focus from mouse clicking or from table key pressing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Override [`QWidget::focusInEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusInEvent) and use the [`QFocusEvent::reason`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfocusevent.html#reason) method of the focus event to get the reason!

Simple sample:

```
void MyWidget::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event) {
    qDebug() << event->reason();
    QWidget::focusInEvent(event);
}
```

**Note:** In case you want to get this information from an already existing widget, you can always install an event filter instead. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter for an example on how do do that.